# mongorestore: zsh: no matches found: mongodb.*

Tags: mongodb

I'm using mongorestore to restore the data in uat_engine file, here is the command

```
mongorestore mongodb://'engine-config-uat_appuser:te$t!P'@mongodb-engine-configuration.test.exp-aws.net:27017/engine-config-uat?authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1 uat_engine/
```

but I'm getting error, how can I fix this?

```
zsh: no matches found: mongodb://tax-engine-config-uat_appuser....
```

Update:
got this error even when I setup the authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1

```
error connecting to host: could not connect to server: connection() error occured during connection handshake: auth error: sasl conversation error: unable to authenticate using mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-1": (AuthenticationFailed) Authentication failed.
```

Comment: You should not disclose your user credentials here! Put connection string in quotes, i.e `mongorestore 'mongodb://engine-config-uat_appuser:te$t!P$t2ds$t2BWO@mongodb-engine-configuration.test.exp-aws.net:27017/engine-config-uat?authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1' uat_engine/`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Hi, after did what you said, I'm getting another error, I update the post, could you take a look?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470